# Dell Optiplex 780 sound driver windows 10 low volume

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, dell-optiplex

I upgraded my Dell Optiplex 780 from Win 7 to Win 10. Everything works fine except even with audio volume at 100% the sound is                                                                                            very, very low.

I tried uninstalling Microsoft's generic driver and re-booting. That did not fix the problem. I also tried several other possible solutions I found on the web. None worked.

Dell's support site says "Dell is not testing or developing Windows 10 drivers for this product."

I hope there's a workaround for this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: use device manager to get the HardwareIDs of the sound chip and google for the name of the chip and get newer drivers from the chip manufacture ebsite

Comment: Thanks. I checked it out. It does look like it's time to buy new speakers, however.

Comment: why? were you able to get the chip name and install newer drivers?

Comment: Yes, but after spending many hours on the problem it seems that new speakers is the best solution for me.